# File not found error in VS code but not in other IDEs

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am noticing an error since I started to import files on VS code. But on other IDEs like python IDLE it works.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root_icon = PhotoImage(file="start_point1.png")
root.iconphoto(False, root_icon)
root.title("Canvas")
root.geometry("600x600")

color_label = Label(root, text="Pen-down Color: ", font=("comic sans ms", 12))
color_label.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.9, anchor=CENTER)

input_box = Entry(root)
input_box.insert(0, "black")
input_box.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.9, anchor=CENTER)

canvas1 = Canvas(root, width=590, height=510, bg="white", highlightbackground="lightgray")
canvas1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Error on vs code:

```
  File "d:\New coding folder\Python projects\canvas\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    root_icon = PhotoImage(file="start_point1.png")
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4120, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4065, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "start_point1.png": no such file or directory
```

but works on python IDLE

Any fix for this?

NOTE: The code is not ready yet but it should work till here.

Comment: It depends what is your current working directory. Other IDEs have a more strictly project structure, but with VSCode you can open any directory. Thus, when executing that python code, you are probably not in the directory you except to be. It would be a good idea to build the image's path, relative to the main script.

Comment: To verify if the relative file exists, you can try something like: `from pathlib import Path; import os; print((Path(os.getcwd()) / "start_point.png").exists())` and if it shows `False` that means you need to reconfigure the working directory